# SwiftUI - Add SceneKit Scene to MacOS project

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

Goal: Add SceneKit Scene to SwiftUI MacOS project (not Catalyst) using UIViewRepresentable

What I did:
Following code works fine when target is SwiftUI iOS.
But when target is MacOS, I get error bellow:

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ScenekitView : UIViewRepresentable {
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

        // create and add a light to the scene
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light!.type = .omni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

        // create and add an ambient light to the scene
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
        ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGray
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

        // retrieve the ship node
        let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!

        // animate the 3d object
        ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = SCNView()
        return scnView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        scnView.scene = scene

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        scnView.showsStatistics = true

        // configure the view
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ScenekitView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScenekitView()
    }
}
#endif
```

[image]

Really appreciate if anyone here can help!

Cheers to all!

Comment: Add `import UIKit` to the top of the file.

Comment: Any ideas what to do if we have an scnp file?)

Comment: What is a scnp file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much to change - just instead of `UIViewRepresentable` conform to `NSViewRepresentable`, and similar replacements from `AppKit` instead of `UIKit`

Here it is (tested with Xcode 11.2):

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit
import AppKit

struct ScenekitView : NSViewRepresentable {

    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<ScenekitView>) -> SCNView {
        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

        // create and add a light to the scene
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light!.type = .omni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

        // create and add an ambient light to the scene
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
        ambientLightNode.light!.color = NSColor.darkGray
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

        // retrieve the ship node
        let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!

        // animate the 3d object
        ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = SCNView()
        return scnView
    }

    func updateNSView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        scnView.scene = scene

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        scnView.showsStatistics = true

        // configure the view
        scnView.backgroundColor = NSColor.black
    }
}
```