# How to use "*.scnp" file in SwiftUI for button click (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swiftui, scenekit

I have `"Explode.scnp"` `SceneKit` file. It's already configured, the texture has been set.

How we can use it in SwiftUI? 
For example, after the button clicks the background will be animated once.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                  Particles()
                }) { 
                  Text("Animate")
                }
            }
     }
}
```

This code works for scn. but how to use it with scnp?

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ScenekitView : UIViewRepresentable {
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

        // create and add a light to the scene
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light!.type = .omni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

        // create and add an ambient light to the scene
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
        ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGray
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

        // retrieve the ship node
        let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!

        // animate the 3d object
        ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = SCNView()
        return scnView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        scnView.scene = scene

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        scnView.showsStatistics = true

        // configure the view
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ScenekitView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScenekitView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Moreover, Xcode version is 11.3.1. 
When I try to create a new file I have this:
[image]

And the extension is SKS... any ideas?

Reworked the code according to @Asperi version:

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ScenekitView : UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var exploding: Bool
    //let scene = SCNScene(named: "SceneKit.scnassets/Explode.scnp")!
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "SceneKit.scnassets/scene.scn")!

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

        // create and add a light to the scene
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light!.type = .omni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

        // create and add an ambient light to the scene
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
        ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGray
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

        // retrieve the ship node
        let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "blow", recursively: true)!

        // animate the 3d object
        ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = SCNView()
        return scnView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        scnView.scene = scene

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        scnView.showsStatistics = true

        // configure the view
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        if exploding {
            if let scene = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "SceneKit.scnassets/scene", recursively: false),
                let particles = SCNParticleSystem(named: "SceneKit.scnassets/Explode", inDirectory: nil) {

                let node = SCNNode()
                node.addParticleSystem(particles)
                node.position = scene.position
                scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
                scene.removeFromParentNode()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Errors related to the path names ...

```
// retrieve the ship node
```

here. Tried .sks, .scnp ... any ideas?

Comment: You can consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60513690/12299030) as example.

Comment: 1. This is a question for iOS
2. There are no descriptions of the use for UIComponents :(

Comment: @Asperi Tried this solution you link me
**[SceneKit] Error: This file cannot be opened (version is too old)**
Do you have any ideas for this?) No scnp files are now supported (only scn)

Comment: Try to change extension from .scnp to .scn

Comment: @Asperi **Explode.scn - unknown decoded object class**

Comment: Did you try to load with SCNParticleSystem [ref](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnparticlesystem/1522772-init)?

Comment: @Asperi I've tried to understand https://www.raywenderlich.com/1255-scene-kit-tutorial-with-swift-part-5-particle-systems
But this is for basic Swift ViewController, not for SwiftUI as I see... Too much information for that) Is it possible just to display the .scnp configured file as a background of the button? As I see there also should be used - geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is modified code with demo. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.4

[image: demo]

*Note: as I don't know your project structure, all dependent resource files were added as Resources (not in Assets). Just in case.*

[image: resources]

```
struct DemoSceneKitParticles: View {
    @State private var exploding = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScenekitView(exploding: $exploding)
            Button("BOOM") { self.exploding = true }
        }
    }
}

struct ScenekitView : NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var exploding: Bool
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "ship.scn")!

    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<ScenekitView>) -> SCNView {
        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

        // create and add a light to the scene
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light!.type = .omni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

        // create and add an ambient light to the scene
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
        ambientLightNode.light!.color = NSColor.darkGray
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

        // retrieve the ship node
        let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!

        // animate the 3d object
        ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = SCNView()
        return scnView
    }

    func updateNSView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        scnView.scene = scene

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        scnView.showsStatistics = true

        // configure the view
        scnView.backgroundColor = NSColor.black

        if exploding {
            if let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true),
                let particles = SCNParticleSystem(named: "Explosion", inDirectory: nil) {

                let node = SCNNode()
                node.addParticleSystem(particles)
                node.position = ship.position
                scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
                ship.removeFromParentNode()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update: variant for iOS**

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo3]

Full module code (resource files as before at top level)

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct DemoSceneKitParticles: View {
    @State private var exploding = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScenekitView(exploding: $exploding)
            Button("BOOM") { self.exploding = true }
        }
    }
}

struct ScenekitView : UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var exploding: Bool
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "ship.scn")!

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

        // create and add a light to the scene
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light!.type = .omni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

        // create and add an ambient light to the scene
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
        ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGray
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

        // retrieve the ship node
        let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!

        // animate the 3d object
        ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = SCNView()
        return scnView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        scnView.scene = scene

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        scnView.showsStatistics = true

        // configure the view
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        if exploding {
            if let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true),
                let particles = SCNParticleSystem(named: "Explosion", inDirectory: nil) {

                let node = SCNNode()
                node.addParticleSystem(particles)
                node.position = ship.position
                scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
                ship.removeFromParentNode()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DemeSKParticles_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DemoSceneKitParticles()
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. There are no imports.
2. I already mentioned above - this is an iOS question (my mistake, already renamed the question and made the tag)
3. Already checked the reference you gave me... The question is already an answer, but I have scnp file instead of scn... I'm new at this, sorry. As I see the scn is a sceen that should contain scnp, right?

Comment: @Oleksandr, your question code contains `NSViewRepresentable` - it cannot be iOS, because available only on macOS, as well as import for AppKit.

Comment: you're right! Thank you. Reworked everything and added your answer with iOS style... however, there are some errors with the path :( Could you give any idea please?

Comment: @Oleksandr, pay attention on Note in my post - where the resources are located, as well here `childNode(withName: "scene"` is not a path, but node name is required.

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: The one more thing I've figured out for myself:
The node is not the file, it is an object inside the .scn file.